# Get class/type from object stored in NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have array of different object like:UISegmentedControl, UILabel, etc. 
How can I take object type(class) if I use 'objectAtIndex'?

I try to do like that:

```
//while my object count ok
while (i< [allChandeableSubview count]) {

  id random = [allChandeableSubview objectAtIndex:i];

  if([random isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]){

     UISegmentedControl *newSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]init];
     newSegment = random;
     newSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

   }
i++;
}
```

But I think it's wrong. Help me please!

Comment: Why u think this is wrong?

Comment: Seems nothing wrong..did u get any error?

Comment: where is the error? can you past the log of your consol if it include any errors?

Comment: Whats up? You can cast it `UISegmentedControl *newSegment = (UISegmentedControl*)random;`.  Pretty sure you could say UIView rather then id, and not sure if this just me but i always use respondsToSelector rather then isKindOfClass I'm sure I heard it was better once...

Comment: Have you log? `NSLog(@"class %@",NSStringFromClass([random class]));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one :)

```
    for (id object in array) 
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])  
        {
             UISegmentedControl *segment = (UISegmentedControl *) object;
             segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
             break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: simple and best solution :P

Comment: my answer is much efficient than the answer you marked as right. Solving problem should not be the aim. The aim should be solving it with most efficient way. Thats what my answer does. So...

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to not recreate a new object:

```
//while my object count ok
while (i< [allChandeableSubview count]) {

  id random = [allChandeableSubview objectAtIndex:i];

  if([random isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]){

     UISegmentedControl *newSegment = (UISegmentedControl*)random;
     newSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

   }
i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all, i'm stuped like a hundred pigs! Post here right, but forget add incriment on my source')))

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can optimise that code a bit:

The code

```
UISegmentedControl *newSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]init];
newSegment = random;
```

does nothing, just assigns `random` to `newSegment` (the `UISegmentedControl` created in the previous line is "lost" as soon as `newSegment` is set to point to another variable, and the `UISegmentedControl` is `dealloc`'ed immediately after it is created by ARC - presuming that you use ARC).

Second, your code will work just fine, but you could say that it is not very object oriented. The idea behind object oriented and late binding languages such as Objective-C is that you just send whatever message you want to your object, and it should respond (i.e., have a method implemented that handles the message).

So if you want to do it more object oriented, then you could create your own subclasses of the UIKit classes in question and add a `setup` method (or some similar name) which you simply call from your code snippet above without having to branch out based on an explicit test of the class.

It would become

```
while (i< [allChandeableSubview count]) {

  id random = [allChandeableSubview objectAtIndex:i];

  [random setup];

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below sample code may help you

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];

UIView *vi = [[UIView alloc] init];

UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] init];


NSMutableArray *marr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:btn, lbl, vi, segment, nil];

for (id obj in marr)
{
    Class cls = [obj class];

    id newObj = [[cls alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"class type %@", [newObj class]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing for iOS 4+ (which i guess you are), then the fastest way would be by using `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock%3a).

So, in your case, i'd write it as following:

```
[allChandeableSubview enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
        UISegmentedControl *newSegment = (UISegmentedControl *)obj;

        newSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;

        /* remove comment to stop enumerating
         *stop = YES;
         */
    }
}];
```